# Cannot invoke "java.security.KeyStore.size()" because "this.myKeyStore" is null - Getting error in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, keystore, java.security

I have a Gradle-based automation framework where I get the * "Cannot invoke "java.security.KeyStore.size()" because "this.myKeyStore" is null "* error when I'm trying to build the project.
Following are the versions that I'm using:
Gradle - 6.8.1
Java - 9.0.4

I've tried to implement the [solution](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-312341) given by Jet Brains for this problem (delete the SSL/cacerts file from the IDE configuration directory), but it hasn't solved my issue yet.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you build successfully by Gradle from the command line? Please add full error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to implement the solution given by Jet Brains for this
> problem (delete the SSL/cacerts file from the IDE configuration
> directory), but it hasn't solved my issue yet.

It works - you need to restart IDE after deletion of 'cacerts' file